# How to activate motors with python3

Tags: python, automation, raspberry-pi, robotics

I am thinking of a way to pack my bag for work in the morning, but I'm trying to automate it with python3, raspberry pi and motors, but I don't know how to program something to make them work. Does anyone know how to do this? I think it might include circuitpython.

Thanks for your time,
Gomenburu

Comment: This would involve too many steps to be answered here. And most of them would be out of the domain of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I might try this with motors instead then, because I heard that is easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. It is explained [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/dc-motors-raspberry-pi-pico). It uses a Raspberry Pi Pico and MicroPython to activate the motors.